# Excel: Find next higest/lowest value - by Date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: example data]

In this example data that is listed by the date (descending), I would like to be able to look up when the value was last higher or lower than the current value, by date.

If the current month is December and the value is 5, the last time it was lower was in November (4) and the last time it was higher was in September (8).

The solutions I have found so far using MATCH/INDEX/etc would return the next higher value as August (6) because it is the next closest higher value to 5. I would like to search down the list by order of date.

This would be used to say, "this month's value is the highest value since September" for example.

Answer (score 1):

If one has the Dynamic Array Formula FILTER:

```
=@FILTER(A3:A7,B3:B7>=B2)
```

and

```
=@FILTER(A3:A7,B3:B7<=B2)
```

[image]

---

if not then we use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A3:A7)/(B3:B7>=B2),1))
```

and

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A3:A7)/(B3:B7<=B2),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Scott. I'm trying to figure out how to get access to dynamic arrays, because they should be available in the version of excel I'm running. The other solution returns the same random value from several rows down, on both versions of the formula.

Comment: on the second group, did you switch the opperand from `>=` to `<=`

Comment: hi Scott - yes I had switched the operand, but I had made another error. I spoke to my company's developer (and he was impressed with your solution, by the way). When I translated this to my own data, I included the top comparison row in the indexing, and it confused the formula. With that small error changed - it works perfectly now! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

*This array (CSE) formula almost solves the issue:*

[image]

- Formula in cell S16:

  ```
  {=INDEX($P$16:$P$21,MAX(IF(($Q$16:$Q$21<=$Q16),$Q$16:$Q$21,0),0))}
  ```
- In cell T16:

  ```
  {=INDEX($P$16:$P$21,MIN(IF(($Q$16:$Q$21>=$Q16),$Q$16:$Q$21,0),0))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

---

**:Edited:**

*I would like to recommend this two step solution finds the closest highest/lowest.*

[image]

- Array (CSE) formula in cell S20:

  ```
  {=INDEX($P$16:$P$21,MATCH(MIN(IF($Q$16:$Q$21>$Q16,$Q$16:$Q$21)),$Q$16:$Q$21,0))}
  ```
- Array (CSE) formula in cell T20:

  ```
   {=INDEX($P$16:$P$21,MATCH(MAX(IF($Q$16:$Q$21<$Q16,$Q$16:$Q$21)),$Q$16:$Q$21,0))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish formula in S20 & T20 with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Thank you Rajesh - this formula finds the closest numerical value that is lower. In the example above if June was 4.9, the formula in T20 would return June instead of November. This is a surprisingly tough thing to do in Excel, it turns out.

Comment: @Woot,, glad to help you,,, yes these formula finds closest lowest and highest,,, 5 ,, rest depends on the values if 4 and 4.9 both are available then formula will return 4. Now, if U feel you any [Accept this as answer](https://superuser.com/tour) as well as Up vote also ,, keep asking ☺